# C | pointers,arrays and segmentation issue

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

I have the following snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 3
typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    int id;
} Rec;
int main() {
    Rec n[SIZE], *p;
    int i;
    char *s[]= { "one", "two","three"};

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        strcpy(n[i].name, s[i]);
        //n[i].id = i;
    }
    p = n;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        //printf("%2d %s\n", p->id, p->name);
        p++;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

I've been sitting on this for like an hour now, and I can't put my finger on the problem.
This program gets kicked out when it hits the `strcpy()`.
I do not know how to solve this, tho I get the feeling that there's a problem with `n`'s allocation.
I did tried to convert it to `malloc`, but results stayed the same..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20997474/694576 if not a duplicate

Comment: couldn't find this post before.
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for `name` member for your `struct`s. You need to allocate memory for them

```
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    n[i].name = malloc(strlen(s[i]) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me see if I got this - 
So I had the name allocated in my struct as a char and not as an array of chars (string) ?

Comment: Yes. Pointer is not array.

Comment: You are missing a ')'

Comment: @Aviad: "*So I had the name allocated in my struct as a char*" no, as pointer to `char`.

Comment: @alk yea, sorry that's what I ment

Comment: @CoolGuy; Fixed now.

Comment: Err. Shouldn't the 1 be *outside* the bracket?

Comment: @CoolGuy; Yes. It should.